# Unwanted redirection to homepage after turning taxonomy to 'public'=>false

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect, 404-error

I have in my site (a site with Elementor, if it's matters) taxonomy 'aaa' with taxonomy term 'bbb'.

When I registered this taxonomy, it was set to 'public' => true.
Now I changed this setting, so it's 'public' => false.

The problem is that when I go this url: sitename.com/aaa/bbb/ it redirects to the homepage, instead of showing 404 page.

How can I fix it?

Thanks :)